# Is there a way to sculpt (with dyntopo enabled) a textured mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting

I'm searching a way to sculpt (with **dyntopo enabled**) a textured mesh.
What I want to do is load an image texture (a portrait) and sculpt it.

Thing is, when I enable dyntopo in sculpt mode, I get this warning and the texture is hidden until I exit the sculpt mode :

[image]

I understand the "concept" of this problem (mesh is edited > UVs are changing > image mapping is changing); but I need to be able to do this - I cannot sculpt without seeing my picture.  Of course, I could disable dyntopo, but then I don't have the precision I need.

- I've tested using the UV project modifier (does the same)
- I've also tested sculpting my mesh in wireframe mode, on a reference image / camera background image : it works, but I don't get the "feeling" of what i'm sculpting.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

A thing that could help would be to have a way to "unsync" modes between two viewport panes (one would be in sculpt mode, the other would be locked in object mode).  But I don't know if this exists.

Any ideas to help me on this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the *Generated* or *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node, you can use *Dyntopo* in *Sculpt Mode*. The question is if this mapping suits your needs and how usable it will be after you've begun sculpting. So this may be not the best answer.

[image: dyntopo texture]

Comment: that is aweSOME!